# Syntactically definable properties and Boolean algebra of definable sets in models

Tags: logic, model-theory

In Baldwin's "Model Theory and the Philosophy of Mathematical Practice" I read this phrase.

> The interaction between the syntactically definable properties of theories and the Boolean algebra of definable sets in their models is crucial.

I was wondering what is meant by this "interaction", to me it is not evident that there should be such relation.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know what "interaction" exactly means, but if we have a first-order theory $T$, we may define equivalence $\sim$ on the set of all formulas (in given language)  as:
$$(\varphi \sim \psi) \Leftrightarrow (T \models (\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi)),$$
i. e. $\varphi \sim \psi$ holds iff $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is satisfied in every model of $T$.

This equivalence is a congruence with respect to operations $\wedge$, $\vee$ and $\neg$, so we may define these operations on the set $B_T$ of classes of equivalence $\sim$, and this gives the structure of Boolean algebra on $B_T$.

So if we have this, we may explore relationship between $B_T$ and Boolean algebras of definable sets in models of $T$. Maybe some of them are isomorphic.